# How could I disable all the over scroll effect in my app?

Tags: android, user-interface

The blue shadow over scroll effect looks really ugly in our app. 
Is there a way to disable all the over scroll effect? You know there are lots of `ScrollView`s and Lists in it... That would be a shame if I have to disable it in every widget that can 
scroll... 
thx~

Comment: Could you post an example image of what scroll effect you are referring to?

Comment: I've never run across a way to do it. Not all devices have the overscroll, and not all of the ones that do look the same while they are doing it. So at least your app is not appearing that way to everyone.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can define a [ScrollViewStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#scrollViewStyle) and [ListViewStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#listViewStyle) in your Theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ListView</item>
    <item name="android:scrollViewStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ScrollView</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MyTheme.ListView" parent="android:Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:overScrollMode">never</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MyTheme.ScrollView" parent="android:Widget.ScrollView">
    <item name="android:overScrollMode">never</item>
</style>
```

Then you have to define your Theme in you `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="ch.citux.example"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="16" android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

<application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme">
```

That's it, no more overscroll ;)

Comment: Small note: this won't work with `NestedScrollView` and `ViewPager`. This answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/17283061/108742 will disable the overscroll everywhere 

Answer (score 41):

You can do it simply

In **layout.XML**

Set

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

In scrollview

Answer (score 24):

I have face same problem

try this code

```
listView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

Answer (score 14):

You can disable all the over scroll effects by opening "res/values/styles.xml" file and adding the item line like bellow:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:overScrollMode">never</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you already used [`setOverScrollMode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setOverScrollMode%28int%29), with `OVER_SCROLL_NEVER`?