# Removing glow using overScrollMode="never" doesn't work

Tags: android

I'm using a Navigation View activity and there is a glow at the bottom when trying to scroll. Is it possible to remove that?

[image]

This is the main activity xml code and I've already used `android:overScrollMode="never"` and also `android:fadingEdge="none"`, which is deprecated. None of them worked. Tested on a Samsung Galaxy S3, Android 4.1.1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main">

        <include layout="@layout/fragment_test" />

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Also, in code

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.setOverScrollMode(DrawerLayout.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
drawer.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set property fadeEdge to none in your layout xmlL.

```
android:fadingEdge="none"
```

try this one also

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

Comment: That's the first thing I tried; and before replying I tried both of  them again. Still not working.

Comment: try that one [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32138010/2183890)

Comment: That only changes the color of the glow, and I thought it could be a workaround but the glow also appears at the top, where the bar is green so [you can see the white glow](http://i.imgur.com/a55Yro9.png). But thanks. I think I will have to create a my own navigation view.

Comment: AKSiddique, just to let you know that I solved the problem using styles. I applied [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12639840/875777). But instead of applying to the application in general, I just applied it to the NavigationView ([code](https://gist.github.com/joseadrian/f224fe9a2e43572a84a3)).